# A question about the Sylvester-Gallai theorem

Tags: combinatorics

For each positive integer $n >1$, let $E(n)$ denote $n$-dimensional Euclidean space with its standard metric. Is the following (higher dimensional) generalization of the Sylvester-Gallai theorem true? Let $S$ be a finite set of poins of $E(n)$ that is not contained in any Hyperplane of $E(n)$. Then there exists a Hyperplane $H$ of $E(n)$ which contains exactly $n$ points of $S$ and is spanned by these $n$ points (i.e. no lower dimensional subspace of $H$ contains these $n$ points).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this generalization is false. A counterexample was given by Motzkin in 1951 for the case n=3.